Theorem 2.4(i) in Valiant-Vazirani paper "NP is as easy as detecting unique solutions"
I have a question about the paper "NP is as easy as detecting unique solutions" by Valiant and Vazirani, specifically the proof of the Theorem 2.4(i).
The proof starts by saying

Clearly, $P_n(S) \ge P(S) \cdot \Pr(H_1 \cap \ldots \cap H_n = \{ 0^n\})$

Here, $S \subseteq \{0, 1\}^n$,
$P_n(S)$ is defined as the probability over random vectors $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ that there is some $i$ between $1$ and $n$ such that $|S_i| = 1$ where $S_i = \{v \in S : v \cdot w_1 = \cdots = v \cdot w_i = 0\}$ where we take dot products mod 2.
Also, $H_i = \{ v \in \{0, 1\}^n : v \cdot w_i = 0 \}$.
And $P(S)$ is defined to be the probability over infinite sequence $w_1, \ldots$ such that there is some $i$ such that $|S_i| = 1$.
Could anyone provide an explanation why the above statement is true?
We can show that the event $\{ \exists i, \lvert S_i \rvert = 1 \& H_1 \cap \cdots \cap H_n = \{0^n\} \}$ is contained in $\{ \exists i \le n, \lvert S_i \rvert = 1 \}$. So, it is sufficient to show that $\Pr(\{ \exists i, \lvert S_i \rvert = 1 \& H_1 \cap \cdots \cap H_n = \{0^n\} \}) \ge P(S) P(H_1 \cap \cdots \cap H_n = \{0^n\})$.
This is equivalent to showing that $\Pr(\{ \exists i, \lvert S_i \rvert = 1 \mid H_1 \cap \cdots \cap H_n = \{0^n\} \}) \ge P(S)$.
My intuition is that the probability of the infinite sequence $\lvert S_i \rvert$ hitting to $1$ is independent of what happens to the sequence of $H_1 \cap \cdots \cap H_k$ for a fixed $k$, since with probability $1$, the intersection of $H_i$ will become $\{0^n\}$ at some point. But I am not really sure how to formalize this idea.

Clearly, $P_n(S)\ge\Pr[\exists i,|S_i|=1& H_1\cap\dots\cap H_n={0}]$. But it’s not clear to me why these two events should be independent (if that is intended to be the argument).

@EmilJeřábek That is as far as I got also. If we assume that $| S_i |$ becomes 1 at some point and $H_1 \cap \cdots \cap H_n = { 0^n }$ then $S_i$ must have become singleton for some $i \le n$. I do not think those two events are independent, but it seems sufficient to show that they have a positive correlation. I am just not seeing it for the case when $0^n \notin S$.

Please don't use "EDIT: more stuff".  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755

To make the post more self-contained, can you give the definition of $H_i = { v : v\cdot w_i = 0 }$?

@NealYoung Added!

For notational convenience define r.v.s

$T_S = \min\{i : |S_i| = 1\}$ (recalling $S_i = S \cap H_1 \cap \cdots \cap H_i$), and
$T_H = \min\big\{i : H_1 \cap H_2 \cap \cdots \cap H_i = \{0^n\}\big\}$.


Then $P(S) = \Pr[T_S < \infty]$ and $P_n(S) = \Pr[T_S \le n]$.

In all outcomes $T_H \ge n$ because $|H_1 \cap \cdots \cap H_i| \ge 2^{n-i}$, so $T_H \le n$ iff $T_H = n$.

It seems to me that the desired inequality can be shown as follows:
$$\begin{align}
P_n(S) & 
{} = \Pr[T_S \le n] &&(\textit{by the definitions}) \\
& {} \ge \Pr[T_S \le n ~~|~ T_H = n]
 ~\times~ \Pr[T_H = n] && (\textit{basic probability}) \\
& {} =
\Pr[T_S < \infty ~|~ T_H = n] 
 ~\times~ \Pr[T_H = n] && (\textit{see Step 10 below}) \\
& {} = \Pr[T_S < \infty] ~\times~ \Pr[T_H = n] && (\textit{see Step 20 below}) \\
& {} = P(S) ~\times~ \Pr[H_1 \cap H_2 \cap \cdots \cap H_n = \{0^n\}]
&& (\textit{by the definitions})
\end{align}$$




Next we argue that $\Pr[T_S \le n ~|~ T_H = n]$ equals $\Pr[T_S < \infty ~|~ T_H = n]$:

The event $T_H = n$ is equivalent to $H_1 \cap H_2 \cap \cdots \cap H_n = \{0^n\}$.

Given this event,
$H_1 \cap H_2 \cap \cdots \cap H_i = \{0^n\}$
and $S_i = S_n$ for each $i\ge n$.

So (by the definitions) $T_S \le n$ iff $T_S < \infty$.

So $\Pr[T_S \le n ~|~ T_H = n]$ equals $\Pr[T_S <\infty ~|~ T_H = n]$,
as desired.




Next we argue that $\Pr[T_S < \infty ~|~ T_H = n]$ equals $\Pr[T_S < \infty]$:

Call $w_i$ redundant if $H_1 \cap \cdots \cap H_i = H_1 \cap \cdots\cap H_{i-1}$.

If $w_i$ is redundant, then $S_i = S_{i-1}$, so, informally, the event $T_S < \infty$ is independent of redundant $w_i$'s.

Formally, consider modifying the random experiment so that redundant $w_i$'s are ignored. That is, redefine $w_i$ to be the $i$th non-redundant random vector. This does not change $\Pr[T_S < \infty]$.

But this modification is exactly the same as conditioning on $T_H \le n$, because each redundant vector doesn't change $H_i$,
while each non-redundant vector cuts $|H_i|$ by a factor of two,
so the distribution of first $n$ non-redundant vectors
is exactly the same as the distribution of the first $n$ vectors
conditioned on $T_H \le n$.  (Out of time here, ask in comments if you have questions.)




Thank you for your answer!
